# soft keyboard is covering bottom sheet dialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've searched all over the related questions on SO, tried basically all of their solutions, and have gotten nowhere. I want to have a bottom sheet modal dialog with a a few `EditText` and other components in it, using `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, which is easy enough.

The problem I am having is that the soft keyboard covers half the dialog. No settings I change seem to make *any* difference in anything. Did something change in the API? No amount of googling seems to be revealing a solution. What currently happens: keyboard does not cover the edit text that is currently selected, but it covers the dialog below it. I want the whole dialog to be visible at all times and move when the keyboard opens.

Here is my Fragment class:

```
public class GoalUpdateFormDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.goal_update_form, container, false);

        assert getDialog().getWindow() != null;

        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Here is the dialog layout file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/goal_update_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/progress_update_hint"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/goal_progress_number_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/goal_progress_box_hint"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/goal_update_comment_box"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/comment"
        android:lines="4"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_attachment_file_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/image_file_name_placeholder"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/delete_attachment_button"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:alpha="0.54"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/attach_file_button"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_file_black_24dp"
            android:alpha="0.54"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/attach_image_button"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/attach_file_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp"
            android:alpha="0.54"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/max_one_attachment"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/attach_image_button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:alpha="0.54"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the activity layout in which the dialog will be displayed over:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.iepone.classroom.view.activities.StudentDetailActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/todo"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pick_image_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pick image"
                android:onClick="onClickPickImage"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/test_comment_box_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test comment box"
                android:onClick="onClickTestCommentBox"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT: Per request, here is the android manifest, with irrelevant bits removed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="REDACTED">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label">
        <activity
            android:name=".view.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.activities.StudentDetailActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you please post your Android Manifest?

Comment: @AbdulAleem Done, manifest added.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very large ui on bottomsheet, best thing is to use NestedScrollView with fixed size;

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

......Other views

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

also have a BottomSheetBehavior like following in your bottomSheet;

define a member variable

```
private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
    }
};
```

and then set it

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.content_register, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, contentView);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

    if( behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior ) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }
}
```

Comment: The layout is not very large; scrolling will never be needed.

Comment: Have you tried with nested scroll view? I have two views in bottomsheet and they work fine on nested scroll view.

Comment: I just tried your code and it seems to work fine. which design library you tried? I am using `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding below line in your manifest activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

For example:

```
<activity
        android:name=".view.activities.StudentDetailActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Your dialog size will be adjusted, whenever keyboard gets up. Hope it helps

Comment: This will apply to the activity a whole, and probably mess up other inputs if any in the same activity. This is an incredibly sensitive area of Android in my opinion as I have seen the same approach yield different behaviors across, different versions of Android. I'm experiencing the same problem at the moment and have not yet found a solution, although this helped shed some insight on how to manipulate your way around the problem. https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/aa9136fb4f5b3a80460fe5f47213985026d20c88/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/util/KeyboardUtil.java

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error.
In my ugly case it was Huawei device specific.
My activity and dialog themes already had the option:

```
<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
```

**The only thing required was:**

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

So the final bottom sheet dialog style is:

```
    <style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    </style>
```

I hope it helps.