# Soft keyboard overlaps views under EditText inside BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I have simply `EditText` and `Button` below this `EditText` in my `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
<ConstraintLayout>
 <EditText/>
 <Button/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

And when soft keyboard opens  it covers evetything(in my case `Button`) below `EditText`.

I'm using `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in my `Activity`.

I've googled a lot and already found similar old questions but no correct answer on them.

[soft keyboard is covering bottom sheet dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966333/soft-keyboard-is-covering-bottom-sheet-dialog)

[How to adjust size of BottomSheet with Edittext and button below it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970023/how-to-adjust-size-of-bottomsheet-with-edittext-and-button-below-it)

Is this some kind of buggy behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the same case. You can just increase padding when soft keyboard will be shown. This solution is available for API 19+.

```
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.os.Build
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import androidx.core.view.updatePaddingRelative

class UnderKeyboardViewElevator(private val decorView: View, private val contentView: View) {

    private var initialPaddingBottom: Int = contentView.paddingBottom

    private var onGlobalLayoutListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val r = Rect()
        decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)

        val height = decorView.context.resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
        val diff = height - r.bottom

        if (diff != 0) {
            val targetPadding = diff + initialPaddingBottom
            if (contentView.paddingBottom != targetPadding) {
                contentView.updatePaddingRelative(bottom = targetPadding)
            }
        } else {
            if (contentView.paddingBottom != initialPaddingBottom) {
                contentView.updatePaddingRelative(bottom = initialPaddingBottom)
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            decorView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener)
        }
    }

    fun enable() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            decorView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener)
        }
    }

    fun disable() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            decorView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener)
        }
    }
}
```

Call `enable()` at `onStart()` and call `disable()` at `onStop()`:

```
    private var elevator: UnderKeyboardViewElevator? = null

    //...

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(context!!)

        val dialogRoot = View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_layout, null)
        dialog.setContentView(dialogRoot)

        val decorView = activity!!.window!!.decorView
        elevator = UnderKeyboardViewElevator(decorView, dialogRoot)

        return dialog
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        elevator?.enable()
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        elevator?.disable()
    }

    //...
```

Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your root view with a ScrollView, preferably with scrollbars=none. The ScrollView will properly not change anything with your layout except being used to solve this problem.

And then set fitsSystemWindows="true" on the view that you want to make fully shown above the keyboard.

Comment: `<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
`
It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `onCreate`:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: It shows keyboard immediately but doesn't help. I've already used `adjustResize`